scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator run in a Docker container fills up memory
Why does this run in 3 seconds when I run it directly on my computer and barely uses any RAM, but fills up 30GB of RAM and 20GB of swap when I run it in a Python Docker container ?
test.py
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator

start_time = time.time()
points = [(0, 1500), (0, 1800), (0, 2000), (0, 2200), (180, 1600), (180, 1900), (180, 2100), (180, 2300)]
values = [5, 20, 25, 40, 2, 10, 15, 20]
points = np.array(points, dtype=np.float64)
values = np.array(values, dtype=np.float64)
interp = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values)
rng = np.random.default_rng()
sampled_angles = 180 * rng.random(size=6000*6000, dtype=np.float64)
sampled_altitude = (2200 - 1600) * rng.random(size=6000*6000, dtype=np.float64) + 1600
interpolated_thicknesses = interp(sampled_angles, sampled_altitude)
print(interpolated_thicknesses[:10])
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(elapsed_time)

Dockerfile
FROM python

WORKDIR /calculator

COPY ./test.py ./test.py
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "test.py"]

requirements.txt
scipy
numpy


Can't reproduce this on latest SciPy and NumPy - I only get 1GB of memory use. Can you post the SciPy/NumPy/Python versions of this where this fails?

Choosing these versions for Python, SciPy and NumPy fixes the issue. I'd be interested to know: how I could have known the right versions to use if I didn't have the script working on my own machine?
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.12

requirements.txt
scipy==1.8.0
numpy==1.21.5


scipy 1.8 is fairly old by now, is there an issue with 1.13 (the latest version) or 1.12? If there's one with 1.13, feel free to open an issue in the scipy github repository.
